# Java - Application crashed on Thread.sleep method

Tags: java, multithreading, crash, sleep

I have a function for my monsters to walk. It will be able to choose the direction and distance randomly and move the monster when called. Right now I have the method being called every frame in the render method:

```
for(Monster monster : monsters) {
            renderer.processEntity(monster);
            monster.monsterWalk();
}
```

This is good so far, but it makes the monster shake around because it is rapidly choosing values, I want it to move somewhere, wait 5 seconds, and then make another decision on where to move.

My problem is when I add the Thread.sleep(x) method, and the screen goes black and the program becomes unresponsive.

Here is the walk method:

```
public void monsterWalk() {

    //Make direction decision
    Random random = new Random();

    switch(random.nextInt(4)) {
    case 0:
        setPosition(new Vector3f(position.x, position.y, position.z += mobSpeed)); //forward
        break;
    case 1:
        setPosition(new Vector3f(position.x, position.y, position.z -= mobSpeed)); //backward
        break;
    case 2:
        setPosition(new Vector3f(position.x += mobSpeed, position.y, position.z)); //right
        break;
    case 3:
        setPosition(new Vector3f(position.x -= mobSpeed, position.y, position.z)); //left
    }

    try {
        Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(5000) + 1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
```

Comment: What sort of UI is this? My guess is that you're in a UI framework which expects the UI thread to stay mostly-unused (as most UI frameworks do) but you're blocking it.

Comment: Im using LWJGL and OpenGL rendering

Comment: Okay, you should specify that in the question. I can't (quickly) find good enough documentation to verify that it does need the UI thread in order to render, but I strongly suspect that's the case.

Comment: I feel like i shouldnt be pausing the thread here though. Because wouldnt that make the whole program sleep? And since its in a loop it would always be sleeping?

Comment: You're right, you shouldn't be pausing the thread - that's the point. That's what `Thread.sleep` does. It won't make *other* threads sleep, so it won't really make "the whole program" sleep unless this is the only thread. But basically you probably want a timer of some description.

Comment: Okay thank you, if you wanna answer I will vote up! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used LWJGL myself, but in almost every UI framework I've seen, there's one thread which is reserved for UI operations:

- You mustn't perform UI operations on any other thread
- You mustn't tie that thread up for any significant time, as the UI can't refresh while it's blocked

In your code, you're calling `Thread.sleep` which blocks the thread for that period of time - if you do that on a UI thread (and if LWJGL works in the same way as those other frameworks) then you're preventing the UI from refreshing while it's blocking.

To perform actions periodically, you should use a timer of some sort. The tricky part is that you'd want the timer to fire *in the UI thread*. Most frameworks provide some sort of dedicated support for this (e.g. [Swing `Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html)) but I don't know if LWJGL does. Hopefully that's enough information to get you started looking for the best approach within LWJGL.

I note the [LWJGL timing documentation](http://wiki.lwjgl.org/wiki/LWJGL_Basics_4_(Timing)) talks about this sort of thing a bit, but it's not *quite* the same. (It also refers to `Display.sync`, which I then can't find in the Javadoc, so it may be referring to an older version.)